# placing img without absolute <css>

Tags: css

Is there anyway to place imgs in position like this without absolute position in css ?

like i want 4 imgs to be in position like a circle check the img link

[image: Photo example]

or if it was by absolute can  it fix to any screen resolution ?

Comment: i want to place it like the photo example by any way rather than absolute or if absolute , then i want it to fit screen resolutions

Comment: What circle? Which img link should be checked? There are various ways to position things in CSS, but you do not specify any specific requirement, and there is no code showing what you have tried.

Comment: the post was edited and i got the answer tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use percentage to define the location and size of your DIVs.  Something like the below for CSS:

```
.images{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#image_one{
    top: 5%;
    left: 10%;
}
#image_two{
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%;
}    
#image_three{
    top: 10%;
    left: 60%;
}
#image_four{
    top: 15%;
    left: 80%;
}
```

Working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc7ea/)

Comment: Nice this is the absolute way but by percentage :)  . so is there another way than absolute ??

Comment: @SamehKhaled You can use the float property, but this requires more mark-up

Comment: The non-position absolute way to do this is with a set of properties currently under consideration called CSS Shapes. Adobe has a page on it with a bunch of helpful links: http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/

You won't be able to use these properties directly just yet. But if you're only targeting uber modern browsers you can use them soon.

Comment: Note with the answer above, the percentages used will be relative to the potential width of the parent element and not the total width of the viewport. A more robust solution would use the `rem` unit (or `em` unit if the browsers you're targeting do not support `rem`s).

Comment: @Zaqx I would strongly advise against using rem or CSS shapes.  They are sparsely adopted by browsers and have not been standardized

Comment: @LloydBanks You'll be interested to know `rem` is [very well supported if you don't need IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem). As stated above, the spec for CSS shapes is still under consideration and very few implementations exist.

Comment: @Zaqx So excluding all versions of IE8 or below makes it well supported?  You're essentially breaking the page for a majority of enterprise users right there.  Also, the % in the child div is only relative to the parent element when the parent div has position defined as absolute or relative.  In the above instance, the % is relative to the viewpoint.  This should have been easy to spot since there wasn't even a parent div.  You should really get a better grasp of what you're talking about before making faulty statements